# How to make Autocomplete Textview focusable in android UI automator?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, android-uiautomator, android-instrumentation

Autocomplete TextView is not displayed in the UIAutomator View hierarchy. Is there any special constraint to make it focusable in UIAutomator?

Checked if the edit text is focusable

[image: screenshot]

Comment: can i show your screenshot?

Comment: @Niceumang find the attachment https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BfCd.png